# ResourceBundle that defaults to English

Tags: java, localization

### Setup

Let's say I have 2 strings files:

```
Strings_en.properties
Strings_fr.properties
```

Let's say English is the default language, and all the strings are present, while French lags behind and some strings are missing.

### Desired behavior

I want to fall back to English in both of these cases:

- When requesting a completely different locale, such as German.

  - `ResourceBundle.getBundle("path/to/Strings", Locale.GERMAN);`
- When requesting a string missing from French.

  - `ResourceBundle.getBundle("path/to/Strings", Locale.FRENCH).getString("only.in.english");`

The first fallback is simple enough: as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)), it's enough to have English as the default locale, for example by setting `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);`.

### Problem

My problem is with the second fallback. If the string is not found in `Strings_fr`, the lookup continues to the "parent bundle": [getObject() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getObject(java.lang.String)). However, `Strings_en` is not the parent of `Strings_fr` and a `MissingResourceException` is thrown.

#### Workaround

A simple fix is to rename `Strings_en.properties` to `Strings.properties`. This makes it the parent bundle for `Strings_fr` (and for any other `Strings_`, for that matter) and looking up missing strings returns the default English versions.

**Problem**: the system now has a *default* localization, but it no longer understands that there is an *English* localization.

#### Workaround 2

When fetching a string, check if it's present in the bundle - if not, fetch it from the English one instead.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("path/to/Strings", Locale.FRENCH);
if (bundle.containsKey(key)) { return bundle.getString(key); }
return ResourceBundle.getBundle("path/to/Strings", DEFAULT_WHICH_IS_ENGLISH).getString(key);
```

**Problem**: this is just a hack, I believe there is an "intended" way to do it.

### Question

Is there a simple way to make `Strings_en` the parent of `Strings_fr`? If not, is it reasonable to for example hardlink `Strings_en` to `Strings`, so that I can keep English as an explicit localization and at the same time as the default one?

Comment: regarding solution 1: *but it no longer understands that there is an English localization*: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("path/to/Strings", Locale.ENGLISH)` will also give you a bundle based on `Strings.properties`

Comment: Yes, but the system does not know it's English. If I ask "what language strings are available?", it cannot include "English".

Comment: Good point, as a matter of fact no piece of code is enumerating the `*.properties` files to determine the supported languages. So I guess it's just a matter of personal preference: it's the _English_ localization, it shouldn't be hidden under _default_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can rename `Strings_en.properties` to `Strings.properties` (making English the default localization) and add a new **empty** `Strings_en.properties`.

Then

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("path/to/Strings", Locale.ENGLISH).getLocale()
```

also returns `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: Wow, cool! Did not think of that. Let me quickly evaluate how it fits into the code and get back to you.

Comment: So, it does the trick. Eclipse's ResourceBundleEditor has survived this correctly, Weblate is confused as hell but whatever, the code works fine. Thanks a lot, accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, another solution:
You can use `ResourceBundle.Control` and `getCandidateLocales` to add custom language candidates (file suffix)

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale, new ResourceBundle.Control() {
    @Override
    public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String baseName, Locale locale) {
      List<Locale> list = super.getCandidateLocales(baseName, locale);
      list.add(new Locale("en"));
      return list;
    }
  }
```